# jQuery Tooltip format

Tags: jquery, html

Hello this is an easy one....I just want to use the jQuery tooltip for these column headers I got.  Im using some custom tags, but I may have it formatted wrong....Its not working...still doing the defualt html mouseover

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
      $("#mgmtViewHeaders ctl[title]").tooltip();
});
```

```
 <table class="data_table" id="mgmtViewHeaders">
    <tr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="Source of Repair" property="sorCode" type="top" defaultSort="true" defaultOrder="asc">SOR</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector in your question matches `<ctl>` elements that have a `title` attribute. There is no `<ctl>` element in HTML, `ctl:` is only the tag prefix of your server-side `sortableTblHdr` component.

Chances are these components are rendered as `<th>` elements in the HTML markup, try matching them instead:

```
$("#mgmtViewHeaders th[title]").tooltip();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following

$("#mgmtViewHeaders [title]").tooltip();